# How to remove square brackets from string in php file?

Tags: php, string

Variable $rds_host contains square brackets which I need to remove. 
The following userdate is part of the amazon ec2 console which runs during the creation of the EC2 instance.

```
        rds_host=`aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"`



UserData="""#!/bin/bash
            yum update –y
            yum install httpd php mysql php-mysql git -y

            echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
            cd /var/www/html
            echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/hello.php

            rds_host=`aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"`


            echo "<?php " >/var/www/html/dbinfo.php  

            $final_str = [];
            $rds_host = preg_match_all('`"([^"]*)"`',$rds_host, $final_str);
            echo $rds_host
            $rds_host = $rds_host[1]
            echo $rds_host


            echo $rds_host;
            echo "define('DB_SERVER', $rds_host);" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php

            echo "define('DB_USERNAME', 'RdsDarius1');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "define('DB_PASSWORD', 'RdsDarius1');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "define('DB_DATABASE', 'RdsDarius1');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "\$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);">> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();">> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "Successfully connected to the RDS instance; $rds_host" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "?>" >> dbinfo.php

            echo $rds_host
            """
```

When the output file is created, it contains brackets which is not good.

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', [
    "rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
]);
define('DB_USERNAME', 'RdsDarius1');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'RdsDarius1');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'RdsDarius1');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo Failed to connect to MySQL:  . mysqli_connect_error();
Successfully connected to the RDS instance; [
    "rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
]
?>
```

I need to somehow get rid of the brackets around the server name.

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER',"rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com");
define('DB_USERNAME', 'RdsDarius1');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'RdsDarius1');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'RdsDarius1');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo Failed to connect to MySQL:  . mysqli_connect_error();
Successfully connected to the RDS instance;"rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
?>
```

Comment: It's a text file? Can't you just use `$rds_host[0]` ?

Comment: No tried that: I get this:   <?php
define('DB_SERVER', [
    "rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
][0]);

Comment: Could you update your question with more code?

Comment: Updated the questions with the entire file.

Comment: Ok but where `$rds_host` come from? I can't see in your code.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If that's the entire file, why can't you simply manually remove the brackets? I mean, what are you trying to achieve? Replace the file with the updated code? Or retrieve the code, change it and parse it? Or retrieve it and write it to a new file?

Comment: is $rds_host an array?

Comment: may be echo $rds_host[0] :)

Comment: I don't think it is an array. Updated the question for clarity. The content is the output of the amazon aws command returning the RDS endpoint containing square brackets.

Comment: Where do you run this command? From php, ssh or what? Where is the `$rds_host` in your file?

Comment: The command runs within the Userdata when creating the EC2 instance. I will update the question with the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to replace the * with 0 in the original string to retrieve only the value.

Here is the final result. (see the 0 in place of the *)

```
rds_host=`aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[0].Endpoint.Address"`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have array, so just implode the result

```
$rds_host = [
    "rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
] 
$rds_host = implode('', $rds_host);
echo $rds_host;
```

Answer (score 1):

it should work:

```
$final_str = [];
preg_match_all('`"([^"]*)"`',$rds_host, $final_str);
$final_str[1];//this is what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question , you need to get the content inside the square brackets from string .

you can use regular expression

```
$rds_host = '[
    "rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
]';
 preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $rds_host, $matches);
echo str_replace('"', '',($matches[1][0]));
```

If you hate regex here is one non recommended eval way

```
$rds_host = '[
    "rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
]';


//echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$rds_host = \"$rds_host\";");
echo $str_final=(json_decode($rds_host)[0]);
```

Comment: No luck, perhaps I should rewrite my question. Not sure why I can not simply use sed. Perhaps since I don't know what the string will contain to search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you can't just use `$rds_host[0]`

You could use json_encode to stringify the array then remove the brackets.

```
$rds_host = ["rdsdarius1.c6pbnndp0mmz.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"];
$rds_host = str_replace(array('[', ']',), '', json_encode($rds_host));
```

Comment: No luck. There are many spaces after the opening and before the closing brackets.